# Receiving Events at Compile-Time?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, postsharp, moles

How do you execute custom code at compile time? Is there an attribute you can use to markup a static method which is then executed on each build?

I'm pretty certain libraries like PostSharp and Moles do something like this. Each of these appear to execute special compile-time routines for the projects they are referenced by.

EDIT: I am referring to the type of compilation done by visual studio, not JIT.

Comment: Execute code in what context? VS has pre-build and post-build step hooks which allow you to run arbitrary executables, and you can also plug into the build system for additional flexibility. But executing code in the context of the compiler is not possible.

Comment: I mean having some arbitrary code you have defined in *your assembly* executed each time a *referencing project* is compiled. I want to ensure all projects referencing my assembly have some code executed on pre-build, but without asking each user to manually add any build events.

Comment: That's a tall order. Sounds like VS extension territory, and certainly not achievable without lots of effort and having users install binaries.

Comment: PostSharp can execute code at runtime, but what is it you really want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Many tools use [Custom Build Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx) to handle updating and manipulating the build process.  This is a fairly simple technique that can be used to put your own logic into the build process.

This doesn't look at your code -but you can write a program that uses reflection to analyze the assemblies post-build and do some logic.